# Не отбрасывается тень от загруженной модельки mlt+obj

Tags: javascript, three.js

У меня есть плоскость и моделька, которую я скачала в интернете. Настройка света:

```
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap;
    // создание точечного источника освещения заданного цвета
    var spotlight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 5000);
    // установка позиции источника освещения
    spotlight.position.set(N, N / 1.5, N / 2 );
    spotlight.castSadow = true;

    spotlight.shadow.mapSize.width = 512;
    spotlight.shadow.mapSize.height = 512;
    spotlight.shadow.camera.near = 0.5;
    spotlight.shadow.camera.far = 1500;

    // добавление источника в сцену
    scene.add(spotlight);
```

Настройка тени у плоскости:

```
plane.receveShadow = true;
```

Настройка тени у модельки:

```
object.traverse(function( child ){
                    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
                        child.castSadow = true;
                    }
                });
```

Я пробовала на нескольких объектах, ни у одного не было тени.
Не знаю, будет ли полезно, но материал плоскости MeshLambertMaterial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я поменяла PointLight на SpotLight, всё заработало